# Playframework : The JPA context is not initialized. JPA Entity Manager automatically

Tags: jpa, playframework

I keep receiving this error although my Bootstrap class looks like this:

```
@OnApplicationStart 
public class Bootstrap extends Job { 
    @Override
    public void doJob() {
        ...
        user.save();
    }
}
```

My User class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
...
```

The @Entity annotation is javax.persistence.Entity. The Model is play.db.jpa.Model.

I'm not doing anything with threads. How do I initialize the JPA context in Play!

Comment: have you tried running play clean against your module? Also, can you paste in the full Bootstrap and User classes?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your jpa settings are correct in application.conf    Use **db=mem** for testing

Comment: I set application.conf to db=mem, but the error remains the same.

Comment: Shot in the dark: check that the job you extend is the play.Job as it is responsible for starting the JPA context and transactions

Comment: It is the play.jobs.Job. I could not find a play.Job. Is there something to be called before the doJob() Method?

Comment: my mistake, you are correct. try posting on the google groups where you might have more luck: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/play-framework